# What is the proper way to check an empty queryset in Django?

Tags: django, django-queryset

```
queryset = demo.objects.filter(name="non_existent_name")

if queryset.exists():
    serializer = DemoSerializer(queryset, many=True)
    return Response(serializer.data)
else:
    return Response(status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)
```

With an empty queryset - I am expecting a 404, but instead get a 200 with an empty serialized Response.  What is wrong with my code?  Why does exists() not work as expected?

Comment: if queryset.exists(): is returning True with an empty queryset

Comment: Possible duplicate to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1387727/checking-for-empty-queryset-in-django

Comment: Can you post full view code?

Comment: or you use the built in shortcut function `get_list_or_404`
[Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#get-list-or-404)

Comment: @tatlar that thread is 10 years old.

Comment: @Xiler this question is 2 years old :)

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```py
queryset = demo.objects.filter(name="non_existent_name")

if queryset:
    serializer = DemoSerializer(queryset, many=True)
    return Response(serializer.data)
else:
    return Response(status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)
```